# is now conform or is now conformed

Tags: middle-voice

May I know Which one is grammatical?

> The implementation after repairing is now conform to the
> specification.
>
> The implementation after repairing is now conformed to
> the specification.

Note to myself: Second one is correct (by StoneyB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Conform* is one of a large number of English [**ergative**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb) verbs which may be used in either a transitive or intransitive sense—let us call these *VERB*<sup>+T</sup> and *VERB*<sup>-T</sup>.

The two senses have closely related meanings. With *VERB*<sup>+T</sup>, an ***Agent*** is depicted as causing a ***Patient*** to undergo an action; with *VERB*<sup>-T</sup>, the ***Patient*** is depicted as being itself the ***Agent*** of the action which it undergoes.

The *VERB*<sup>-T</sup> usage is similar to the passive voice in that the subject of the verb is the *Patient* of the action; it is similar to the active voice in that the subject of the verb is also the *Agent* of the action.

- Because with *VERB*<sup>-T</sup> the action has similarities to both active and passive voice, this usage is sometimes called a *middle voice*, particularly in languages which have distinct inflections to express it. Some languages which inflect nouns for case express the distinction by casting the subject in the object case when *VERB*<sup>-T</sup> is in play. English does not have these inflections, so you have to infer which is meant from the form of the sentence.

One classic example is *shave*<sup>†</sup>:

> Fred shaved<sup>+T</sup> John.
>   Fred shaved<sup>-T</sup>.  *This may also be expressed* Fred shaved<sup>+T</sup> himself.

Another example is *cook*:

> Fred was cooking<sup>+T</sup> eggs.
>   Eggs were cooking<sup>-T</sup> on the stove.

*Conform* works the same way. In your examples, *implementation* is the *Patient* of the action of the verb. If you want to cast *implementation* as the subject of the sentence may use either *conform*<sup>-T</sup> in the active voice or *conform*<sup>+T</sup> in the passive voice:

> The implementation ... *conforms*<sup>-T</sup> to the specification.
>   The implementation ... *is conformed*<sup>+T</sup> to the specification.

But *is conform*—*BE* + *VERB*<sup>infinitive</sup>—is simply not a grammatical English construction.

---

> <sup>†</sup>Recall the famous paradox: *The barber shaves every man in town who does not shave himself. Who shaves the barber?*

Answer (score -1):

I think both are okay.

> The implementation after repairing is now **conform to** the specification. 
>   The implementation after repairing is now **conformed** to the specification.

Note that WordWeb describes **[conform to](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=conform%20to)** and **[conform](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/CONFORM)** both as verbs.

Comment: The first doesn't work: *BE + infinitive* is not a grammatical English construction. You may say *The implementation now **conforms** to the specification, employing the intransitive sense of the verb.

Comment: @stoney I provided the link. The whole phrase is stated as a verb. In my last sentence I already clarified it.

Comment: I'm talking about the collocation *is now conform to*. You can say *is now conformED* or *is now conformING* (except we'd never say that with a stative verb) or *now conformS*, but you can't say *is now conform*.

Comment: @StoneyB *The old term was something different but it is **now referred to** as ....* is wrong? Also, please note that **conform to** (with *to*) is a verb phrase as described in WordWeb.

Comment: *Is now referred to* is fine; it uses the past participle with *-ed* to form a passive. *Is now conformED to* would too, but *is now conform to* does not. The role of *to* doesn't affect that.